# Signal generated by libnm object document

Tags: networkmanager

I see some libnm sample code to catch signal of network state.

```
g_signal_connect (applet->nm_client, "notify::state",
                  G_CALLBACK (foo_client_state_changed_cb),
                  applet);
```

Where can I find the document that describe about signals generated by libnm object and callback function prototype?

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything in [docs](https://networkmanager.dev/docs/libnm/latest/). All class which is sending some signal, have section Signals.

Second option is to connect to `notify::<property_name>` (properties name you can find out in docs too).

Maybe there are more options to connect to property, but I'm a beginner in this subject, so maybe I don't now every available option.